# How to name Multiple Outputs of a Function (Tuple)?

Tags: halide

Say I have a Generator for generating Ahead of Time compiled function something like the following.

```
Halide::Func build(){
   Halide::Func func1("func1"), func2("func2"), func3("func3");
   Halide::Func result("result");
   func1(x,y) = input(x,y) * 3; func2(x,y) = y; func3(x,y) = x + y;
   result(x,y) = Halide::Tuple({func1(x,y), func2(x,y), func3(x,y)});
   return result;
}
```

After compiling to object and header files, the signature of the generator looks something like below.

```
int myFunction(buffer_t * input, buffer_t * result_0_buffer, buffer_t * result_1_buffer, buffer_t * result_2_buffer);
```

**How can I rename the output arguments of myFunction ?**

`result_0_buffer => func1`

`result_1_buffer => func2`

`result_2_buffer => func3`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile a Pipeline and add individual Funcs to the Pipeline as outputs rather than using a Tuple, the result parameters should take the names of the Funcs added to the Pipeline. I haven't tested this, but it looks like so:

    `Halide::Pipeline pipeline({func1, func2, func3});
    pipeline.compile_to(...);`

The Pipeline is also more flexible in that the outputs can have different shapes/dimensions.